# gRPC vs WebFlux (Project Reactor)

Tags: grpc, spring-webflux, project-reactor, grpc-java

Please ignore this question. I had wrong setup which caused poor performance of gRPC.

---

Is it OK to compare GRPC vs Project Reactor?

I just wanted to compare the performance of REST and GRPC. I do not see that GRPC is any faster than reactor. In fact it is worse.

**GRPC set up:**

```
api-server --> grpc-server
```

- This grpc server responds 1000 "Hello" using server-side streaming for each request from api-server.
- The api-server returns `Flux<String>`

**WebFlux Setup:**

```
api-server --> rest-server
```

- This rest server responds 1000 "Hello" as `Flux<String>` for each request from api-server.
- The api-server returns `Flux<String>`

I did the performance test for 10000 iterations with 10 concurrent users.

The WebFlux setup is much much faster than GRPC. I am kind of curious if it is gRPC really faster? If yes, in which cases?

**Note:** The request and response payload is very small in size in both cases.

Comment: Could you please quantify "much faster" and share qps or similar? There's many ways you can mess up a benchmark, so numbers would be helpful to know if the results are close to expected. How long does the benchmark take to run (wall time)?

Comment: @EricAnderson, Yes, I had wrong understanding. grpc turned out to be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at the rsocket protocol https://rsocket.io for something even closer, reactive streams but across the network. grpc has more higher level components for the rpc stuff (stubs generation, etc...) but as a result one could argue rsocket gives you more control